# Square root of a number to 100 decimal places

Tags: r

How can I get the square root for a number to 100 decimal places in R?

I've looked into the `gmp` and the `Rmpfr` packages. I can't figure out how I would use them for square roots, `(pow.bigz(2,0.5)=1)`
but even if I did, I'm not sure how accurate it would be, since I've found that after about 25 decimal places, the digits aren't reliable

eg

```
mpfr(1/3,400)
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  400   bits 
# [1] 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
```

and

```
as.bigz(1e50/3)
# Big Integer ('bigz') :
# [1] 33333333333333337607355566542238210608487100055552
```

Comment: The downvote is a bit harsh - G. Grothendieck's answer below is certainly not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is computing one third prior to `mpfr` so it has already lost precision by the time `mpfr` sees it.  Do it this way:

```
mpfr(1, 400)/3
```

Comment: Thank you. From this it of course follows the sqrt(mpfr(2,400)) is the square root of two.